# concat string in batch makes trouble

Tags: windows, string, batch-file, concatenation

I want to concat 2 variables (see example) without this --> " <--
Now:

```
set upvar="update/"
echo %upvar%%1
```

**Output:** "update/""example.txt"

With this output, I cannot make my copy-commands - so how can i concat these variables without this " sign?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Batch files don't require quotation marks around strings.  So, you can simply change the first line to:

```
set upvar=update/
```

Here's a [link](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) that has some useful tips about string manipulation in batch files.